# Directed Graph Markup Language No Longer Recognized with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, dgml

After installing Visual Studio 2017, I just noticed that my [Directed Graph Markup Language(.dgml)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQ3eJ.png) files can no longer be opened in a visual-designer for editing; it only opens to see the internal format of the file. Does anyone know how I can fix this? Is .DGML no longer supported with Visual Studio 2017?

In case some people arent aware of what this is/was, here's a picture:

[image]

And here is my .dgml file, which was recognized and loaded in Visual Studio 2015 without a problem.

https://pastebin.com/xaYsiyzm

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out. I guess that Visual Studio no longer installs this by default. You have to go in to the Visual Studio Installer->Modify, and tick the box.

[image]

Comment: Probably a candidate for Visual Studio User Voice -- when attempting to open a file with an extension that VS *can* recognize, it prompts you to go to the Tools and Features in the VS Installer...

Comment: @AlanMcBee That's a great idea!